# Replicate data from one RDS server to another

Tags: rds

Can we replicate data from one RDS server to another? Or can we set master slave relationship between two RDS servers?
Should we replicate data from non RDS instance to RDS instance?

Answer (score 1):

RDS can replicate from external mysql and also be a master of an external slave. It depends on your usecase if you "should" do it.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.External.Repl.html

While i guess you could setup replication between two RDS instances yourself I don't see why you should since starting a RDS read replica is just a few clicks in AWS console or an api call.

Comment: Also, multi-AZ RDS replicates between primary and backup. See https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/multi-az/

Answer (score 1):

It can be possible to replicate data from RDS to RDS. It is also possible to replicate data from RDS to some other MySQL server.

#### Steps:

- You can go creating your ec2 server and install MySQL.
- Change configuration to replicate data.

  - That will require additional work to manage ec2 instance in case if your data is *increasing and crossing the server limits*
- Then you have to do all the manual work again to replicate data as we can't increase storage in ec2 server.
- RDS provides an easy mechanism to create `Read replica via a few clicks`. (***Note:*** replica is quite a costlier option.)
- But going with that you will save manual work one person salary who will be managing the database and doing these setups regularly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using postgresql database on RDS then you can use bucardo for asynchronous replication. You need to create a EC2 or use can use local system also but it will not be fast enough. 
Use the following tutorial if you want to use bucardo.

https://www.installvirtual.com/how-to-install-bucardo-for-postgres-replication/

Answer (score -1):

I think you can using snapshot to clone another rds database